Fill in Word forms on SharePoint site
I have a couple of forms in Word files that must remain as Word files with existing formatting.
These forms need to be filled in by 50 people, some people may need to fill in the same form up to 10 times.
I would like to distribute and collect these forms using a SharePoint site.
So far I have created a document folder and added the form as a template.
I would prefer if users could simply click a button (without the document template part)  which will create a copy of the form and open it for filling in.
Also I would like only site editors to see forms created by other people.
I am using SharePoint online with an educational 365 license.

Welcome to SuperUser. Is this a business/enterprise environment? Have you spoken with your IT support staff or Sharepoint development/support teams to see what they suggest? Is this Sharepoint online, or an on-prem/locally hosted environment? Which Sharepoint version? Please note that Superuser is more for end-user computing problems. Enterprise problems are not entirely off topic, but in general your first step does need to involve going to enterprise support resources before coming here for this sort of question.

Oh, good, we've moved the questions to a site specifically about Sharepoint. This should get your question in front of people more familiar with that toolset.
